# How to configure a Jenkins job to run a unit test

Tags: php, unit-testing, jenkins, continuous-integration, kohana

After created a job for my Kohana-based project in Jenkins, I cannot figure out how to config the job in order to run unit tests. Basically I used the template from http://jenkins-php.org/, but Kohana has its unique settings which does not allow me to run unit tests as normal php projects. Since phpunit command is not run from CLI, I kept getting errors:

```
 [exec] ErrorException [ 1 ]: Call to undefined method Log::instance() ~ SYSPATH/classes/kohana/core.php [ 336 ]
 [exec] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Construct-A-Cost Deployment Build/workspace/application/bootstrap.php on line 70
 [exec] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Log::instance() in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Construct-A-Cost Deployment Build/workspace/system/classes/kohana/core.php on line 336
```

In the build.xml, I have

```
 <target name="phpunit" description="Run unit tests with PHPUnit">
   <mkdir dir="${basedir}/application/cache" />
   <mkdir dir="${basedir}/application/logs" />
   <exec dir="${basedir}/application/tests" executable="phpunit" failonerror="true" />
 </target>
```

In the application/tests/phpunit.xml, I got

```
<phpunit colors="true" bootstrap="../../modules/unittest/bootstrap.php">
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Calculation Tests">
        <file>./classes/controller/calculation.php</file>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Anyone can share your experience on setting Kohana job in Jenkins? Thanks!

**Update**: running the same test from CLI, it works in Windows XP with PHPUnit 3.6.11, but it doesn't work in Ubuntu Server with PHPUnit 3.7.18

Comment: looks like jenkins call a log class with the same name as the kohana log class. seems like you ran into a nameconflict...

Comment: Try to have a look here, it might help http://blog.loftdigital.com/posts/jenkins-ci-and-php
By the way it runs phpunit from command line.

Comment: @ZdenekMachek, thanks for the run phpunit from CLI hint, didn't think of that, it might be able to solve the problem as I don't get errors when running phpunit from command line. Definitely will give it a try!

Comment: Some updates: running the same test from CLI, it works in Windows XP with PHPUnit 3.6.11, but it doesn't work in Ubuntu Server with PHPUnit 3.7.18, I really cannot figure that out :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem by these two steps:

```
sudo pear update-channels
sudo pear upgrade-all
```

It updates all the packages including PHPUnit.